# How can I test if a variable matches another value and move to another function?

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, programming, vim

I am writing a script where I store a predetermined line of text into a string (we will call `abc`). I am storing the results from `grep -iqs $USER file` (we will call `def`) into another string.

How can I test if `$abc` matches content in `$def` and if it does, move onto next function? If it does not, prompt user for input.

This is my attempt thus far:

```
firstFunction() {
abc="$USER content";               #text stored as string
def=`grep -iqs $USER /file`;       #results of grep stored to string
if [[ $def = "$abc" ]]; then       #test if result from grep command matches text in
   secondFunction                  #string $def. If true, move to secondFunction. If
else                               #false, prompt user.
   echo "Message to user with a y/n prompt"; read prmt;
fi;
if [[ $prmt != "y" || $prmt != "n" ]]; then prmt
elif [[ $prmt == "y" ]]; then
   sed -i "s/$def/$abc/g" /file    #If user chooses y at prompt, replace $abc with $def
elif [[ $answer == "n" ]]; then    #in file. If user chooses no at prompt, move to 
   secondFunction                  #secondFunction.
fi;
clear;
};
```

Environment titles have been changed but the concept behind the snippet should be clear.

Comment: Do you still need help with this? Or have you solved it already?

Comment: I have solved this particular issue using `case....esac`

Comment: please add your own solution as answer, that way everyone can benefit ;)

Comment: Well as mentioned, I solved that one particular issue...which is only part of a larger project overall. I found another method where I will be trying to parse options rather than create menus. I will post a link to the source for it when I finish.

Comment: Oke nice! if I remember correctly the book 'learning the bash shell' also has some examples on how to do this...

Answer (score 2):

**First** of all, because you used `grep` with `-q` argument, the value of `def` variable will always be equal with an empty string. From `man grep`:

> ```
> -q, --quiet, --silent
>        Quiet;  do  not  write  anything  to  standard   output.    Exit
>        immediately  with  zero status if any match is found, even if an
>        error was detected.  Also see the -s  or  --no-messages  option.
>        (-q is specified by POSIX.)
> ```

**Second**, you should think a little bit logic. This expression:

```
$prmt != "y" || $prmt != "n"
```

is always in any programming language evaluated as **true**:

- if `$prmt = "y"`, then **for sure** `$prmt != "n"`, so your expression is **true**
- if `$prmt = "n"`, then **for sure** `$prmt != "y"`, so your expression is **true**
- in any other cases is clear that your expression is true.

**Third**, your function should look like:

```bsh
firstFunction() {
    abc="$USER content"
    def=`grep -is $USER /path/to/file`
    if [[ $def = "$abc" ]]; then
       secondFunction 
       return                            #does not make sense to go ahead
    else
       echo "Message to user with a y/n prompt"
       read prmt
    fi
    while : ; do
    if [  "$prmt" = "n" ]; then 
       secondFunction
       return                            #does not make sense to go ahead
    elif [ "$prmt" = "y" ]; then
       sed -i "s/$def/$abc/g" /path/to/file
       return                            #does not make sense to go ahead
    else
       echo "Message to user with a y/n prompt"
       read prmt
    fi
    done
}
```

Or, as you said, you can use `case` statement.

See also:

- [Introduction to if](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html)
- [Using case statements](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html)
- [Function syntax](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_11_01.html#sect_11_01_02)
- [Examples using grep](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_04_02.html)